# Java JSONSimple Parser

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse data from a php script to my Java application with a JSONArray.
This is the php output:

```
{"name":"test"}
```

This is my Java code that I got from the JSONSimple documentation:

```
try {
    String urlParameters = "test";    
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Test");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

    writer.write(urlParameters);
    writer.flush();

    String line;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

        Object obj=JSONValue.parse(line);
        JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;

        System.out.println(array.get(0));     
    }

    writer.close();
    reader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print("ERROR: 1");
    return;
}
```

It doesn't show any errors in de editor but when I try to run the program I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

Does anybody know hot to fix this problem? Any help wil be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSON Object:

```
{ "key1": "value", "key2" : "value2", ....}
```

A JSON array: `[ object1, object2,...]`

You are trying to cast an object as an array, that's the problem:

```
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(line);
JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj; //INCORRECT
```

Cast it to a `JSONObject` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(your php string);
// get a String from the JSON object  
String firstName = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php output {"name": "test"} is a JSONObject,not JSONArray ..

You cannot typecast an JSONobject to JSONarray